# How to submit ruble bundle to Aptana Team

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I have created a Aptana Studio 3 bundle for "Twitter Bootstrap" and check the Aptana Wiki for submitting it to Aptana so bootstrap users can easily install the bundle from their application.

**From Wiki**

> The current list comes from the Rubles hosted on the Aptana GitHub
>   servers. If you wish to contribute a new Ruble, please contact us
>   about adding your content to our repository

But how?

Repo url for the bundle is:

https://github.com/berkayunal/Twitter-Bootstrap-Bundle

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could always use the email displayed on their "Contact Us" page, and assume that the general email will be directed to someone appropriate.

Just by making it available on Github, I'm sure people are trying it out. You can easily add that Ruble to any Aptana Studio installation, by simply checking your code out to the Aptana Rubles directory (`~/Documents/Aptana Rubles`on Mac/'nix).